# SwiftUI TabView brightness views vertical location

Tags: swiftui, navigation, vertical-alignment, tabview, brightness

I'm trying to change the brightness of a TabView in SwiftUI, but whenever the brightness toggles, the sub-views change their vertical position. This is highly mysterious to me, as it seems strange for brightness to have any influence at all on the position of views.

If you've been following my past few questions, you might recognize that I want to change the brightness because I want to dim the background view as a new view slides up (on the press of a button). That's why, in the sample code, we must include the Z-Stack.

Sample Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var press: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    Button(action: { press.toggle() }) {
                        Text("Toggle")
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square.stack").font(.title)
                    Text("View One")
                }
                
                NavigationView {
                    Button(action: { press.toggle() }) {
                        Text("Toggle")
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                    Text("View Two")
                }
            }
            .brightness(press ? -0.1: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the multiple `NavigationViews` that are inside the `TabView` You really are supposed to have only 1 `NavigationView` at the root of the view hierarchy. Using multiple `NavigationViews` is discouraged and can lead to unexpected results, like this. Therefore, the inside of the `body` should be:

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        TabView {
            Button(action: { press.toggle() }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "square.stack")
                Text("View One")
            }
            
            Button(action: { press.toggle() }) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
                Text("View Two")
            }
        }
        .brightness(press ? -0.1: 0)
    }
}
```